# Filling a table cell with a colour x% wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do not know if there is a name for what I am trying to achieve. I need to create a table like the one shown in the picture below.

[image]

The numbers in the cells are just for demo purposes, but what should happen is that when the WT% of CO2 is 4.11%, the cell should be filled 4.11% with a blue colour - kind of like a bar chart.

Is there a name for this and is there a plugin I can get to do it for me?

Comment: Can you share your HTML/ CSS with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to pick the value in the cell and put in the width.

Consider the following sample table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><div>35<span class='progress'>&nbsp;</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td><div>100<span class='progress'>&nbsp;</span></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td><div>80<span class='progress'>&nbsp;</span></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In jQuery, we can pick the value in the cell(which is in div to keep it outside the progress bar) and set that value as the width of the progress bar which already has a background color.
Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt7ko9dr/)

This is to give you an idea on how you can modify your code to achieve what you need. No ready made answers in StackOverflow.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use some background `div` with percent width:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.progress {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
td {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>N2</td>
    <td class="relative">
      <div class="progress" style="width:35%;"></div>35
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CO2</td>
    <td class="relative">
      <div class="progress" style="width:92%;"></div>92
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```